# Challenging Riemann Integration Problems for Students

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I'm looking for some challenging problems of the type: "Prove this is integrable from scratch" or "Calculate the integral from scratch". For example, I'm looking for for problems to give students roughly of the difficulty of:

Prove $f$ defined by $$f(x) := \begin{cases}
                                   0 & x \, \, \text{irrational} \\
                                   \frac{1}{q} & x = \frac{p}{q} \, \, \text{in lowest terms} \\
  \end{cases} $$

is integrable on $[0,1]$ by definition.

Problems can be in more than one dimension, such as proving that the product of two monotone functions of different variables is integrable on a square.

Comment: The powers $x^n$ and continuous except for a set of measure zero is all anyone ever needs to do from scratch. Anything more and you just wasting your students' time.

Comment: Well, exponential functions such as $2^x$ aren't too hard to integrate by hand either.  Otherwise, I'd tend to agree with Hellen's comment.

Comment: You could use some functions on $[0,1]$ so that $f(x) + f(1-x)$ is easy to integrate.